# Can not get the required XML format via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm trying to achieve the following XML format via PHP, Of course my attributes are different then this example.  Can anyone please tell me how I can achieve this.  Thank you

```
<states>
  <state name="Alaska" colour="#ff0000">
    <point lat="70.0187" lng="-141.0205"/>
    <point lat="70.1292" lng="-141.7291"/>
    <point lat="70.4515" lng="-144.8163"/>
    <point lat="70.7471" lng="-148.4583"/>
    <point lat="70.7923" lng="-151.1609"/>
     ....
 </state>
</states>
```

and this is how far I got

```
<xml>
<locations>
    <location uname="John Smith" postcode="LS12" county="Leeds" colour="#ff0000">
    <point lat="53.7965" lng="-1.55859"/>
    </location>
</locations>
<locations>
    <location uname="John Smith" postcode="LS12" county="Leeds" colour="#ff0000">
    <point lat="53.7957" lng="-1.55831"/>
    </location>
</locations>
<locations>
    <location uname="John Smith" postcode="LS12" county="Leeds" colour="#ff0000">
    <point lat="53.7954" lng="-1.55802"/>
    </location>
</locations>
...
</xml>
```

with the following code;

```
$query = "Some Query";
$result = mysqli_query ($dbh, $query ) or die ( mysqli_error () );

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement ( '<xml/>' );
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $result ) ) {

    $draw = $xml->addChild ( 'locations' );
    $location = $draw->addChild ( "location" );

    $location->addAttribute ( 'uname', $row ['uname'] );
    $location->addAttribute ( 'postcode', $row ['pcode1'] );
    $location->addAttribute ( 'county', $row ['county'] );
    $location->addAttribute ( 'colour', $row ['colour'] );

    $point = $location->addChild ( 'point' );
    $point->addAttribute ( 'lat', $row ['lat'] );
    $point->addAttribute ( 'lng', $row ['lng'] );
}
mysqli_close ( $dbh );
$fp = fopen ( "get_locationsXML.xml", "wb" );
fwrite ( $fp, $xml->asXML () );
fclose ( $fp );
```

Query works fine I've tried it in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I'm a little confused how you've managed to construct the code that you have, but are unable to sufficiently understand how to modify it to produce your desired results.  It's really not a very difficult step—perhaps if you elaborate where you're getting stuck, we can teach you something rather than spoonfeeding an answer from which you're unlikely to learn anything useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem I have is here     `$point = $location->addChild ( 'point' );
    $point->addAttribute ( 'lat', $row ['lat'] );
    $point->addAttribute ( 'lng', $row ['lng'] );`  I'm not getting the the full data of   `lat` and `lng` before it loops again for the next `location`.  am I making any sense ???

Comment: What do you mean "*I'm not getting the full data...*"?  The output that you're showing in the question (under "*this is how far I got*") shows values of `lat` and `lng`.  And if that's where you're getting stuck, what does the first block of XML in your question (under "*I'm trying to achieve the following XML format*") have to do with anything?

Comment: Example gives you full list `points` where as my code gives me one `row` at a time.

Comment: Aha, I understand now.  Your example of how the data should look was confusing me!  It would be more clear if it used your actual element and attribute names instead of `<states>` etc.  The solution involves ensuring that the resultset is sorted appropriately, then keeping track of the last-seen "location" in order to determine when the current record represents a different one—how best to do this will depend somewhat on your actual schema... presumably your query involves a join between a locations table and a points table, and there's a PK on the locations side of the join? You can use that.

Comment: You achieve the result by changing the order and names to the elements you want to create. You didn't share so far what stands in your way to do so, so it's not clear where you hit the wall. For example why do you create the XML document with the document element named *xml* while you want to have it named *states*?

Comment: **...Of course my attributes are different then this example...**  Thanks for your reply I have managed to do it by changing the **Table** and **query** also slight bit of  `XML` code.

Comment: @Tony: Good to read! If you can, place it as an answer below. You can highlight which changes "did it" and what the rationale is behind that. This will not only make your initial post more clear you've also documented your solution and you can then mark the question as answered later on.